# Update keys in unbalance dictionaries with different number of keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'd like to exchange the key in d1 for key in d2 based on the same list values. For instance, I have the following original dictionaries:

```
d1={'work': ['fulltime','partime','intership','volunteer'], 
    'thing': ['science', 'grammar', 'universe', 'unicorn']}

d2={'working': ['fulltime','partime','intership','volunteer','working']}
```

I know that updating the key dictionary as follows would add the updated key at the end of the dictionary which is not intended in this case:

```
d1['working']=d1.pop('work')
```

How can I update the key under this circumstances?

```
{'working': ['fulltime', 'partime', 'intership', 'volunteer'],
 'thing': ['science', 'grammar', 'universe', 'unicorn']}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `dict` comprehension. Note that this assumes the key from `d1` is an **unique** substring for a key from `d2`:

```
{k2 if k1 in k2 else k1: v for k1, v in d1.items() for k2 in d2}
```

Output:

```
{'working': ['fulltime', 'partime', 'intership', 'volunteer'],
 'thing': ['science', 'grammar', 'universe', 'unicorn']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Chris' answer you could also check if list values of `d1` are in `d2`:

```
{k2 if set(v1).issubset(set(v2)) else k1: v1 for k1, v1 in d1.items() 
     for k2, v2 in d2.items()}
```

To achieve the comparison I convert the list values to sets.